# Scroll inside an item renderer result in an empty item

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, scroll, itemrenderer

I'm developing a mobile app. I have a view with an horizontal list, each item has a long description so I would need a vertical scroll for that independent information. I'm trying to add an scroll as a Child of an itemRenderer. And I dont get it. Anyone knows what I'm doing bad?
I have a class with inheritance of ItemRenderer (I tried BaseRenderer from AsFusion too, that it seems to have more performance for mobile apps, with the same result). 
And here is the part of the scroll from my code:

```
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        scroller = new VScrollBar();
        scroller.percentHeight = 100;
        scroller.setStyle('right', 0);
        scrollGroup = new Group();
        scrollGroup.percentHeight = 100;
        scrollGroup.percentWidth = 100;
        super.addElement(scroller);
        super.addElement(scrollGroup);

        scroller.viewport = scrollGroup;
    }
```

I also tried

```
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        scroller = new Scroller();
        scroller.percentHeight = 100;
        scroller.percentWidth = 100;
        scrollGroup = new Group();
        scrollGroup.percentHeight = 100;
        scrollGroup.percentWidth = 100;
        super.addElement(scroller);
        super.addElement(scrollGroup);

        scroller.viewport = scrollGroup;
    }
```

And the result is the same. An empty item in the list. I can change page (pagesnapping of the list horizontal scroll) and the next item is also empty. If I delete addElement(scroller) I can see the items perfectly, but without the vertical scroll that I really need. So the problem is in the scroller. Any idea what I'm doing so bad?? Please? I need the solution in actionscript, I have more itemrenderers done and I will make inheritance, and the performance for the mobile is better in actionscript. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, with the guidance of Grigorash Vasilij I noticed that the content of the scroller was not showing because in the group the content size was 0 and private visible variable was false. So the percent sizes of the scroller was not working, I updated it in the method updateDisplayList.

```
    override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ):void
    {                       
        super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );

        scroller.width = unscaledWidth;
        scroller.height = unscaledHeight;
        ...
    }
```

After that, the scroller was horizontal, then the horizontal scroll wasn't work, I wanted a verticalScroll if needed in the item Renderer, so after the constructor of Scroller I set the horizontalPolicy of the scroll equal to off. The result is the next:

```
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        scroller = new Scroller();
        scroller.percentHeight = 100;
        scroller.percentWidth = 100;
        scroller.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
        scrollGroup = new Group();
        scrollGroup.percentHeight = 100;
        scrollGroup.percentWidth = 100;
        addChild(scrollGroup);
        scroller.viewport = scrollGroup;
        addChild(scroller);

    }
```

My class is inheriting of [BaseRenderer from Asfusion](http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/mobile-itemrenderer-in-actionscript-part-4) If you inherit of itemrenderer use addElement instead of addChild.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used scroll bars in an item renderer... But you might check out the [Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html) component? Something like this:

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Group>
            <Your_components_here />
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Not sure if it would behave any different though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need the solution in actionscript. (It is recommended for big itemrenderers in mobile apps) I will edit my question. I think that I have done above is the same as you in mxml. But It doesn't work ><. I don't know if it works with mxml, but If it works it must be any way that works in actionscript.

Comment: You can instantiate a Scroller in Actionscript ... just create one and add a Group to it, as shown above...

Comment: A Scroller uses VSCrollBar and HScrollBar so it's possible that it's doing something that your code above might not be doing.

Comment: I have tried in actionscript add the group to the scroller and there is not way, it didnt let me. The correct way is asign the group to the viewport of the scroller. Ok I will search something about VScrollBar in actionscript. I will tell you the result.

Comment: Interesting, I never tried that till just now. I briefly looked at the code for Scroller -- the addElement says to use not to add children but use the `viewport` as you're already doing w/VScrollBar. One thing I noticed in Scroller.as (line 1100) is they do this: `viewport.clipAndEnableScrolling = true;` I think you just need to tweak your code to get there... maybe look at Scroller.as :)

Comment: Thanks for help me, but I dont understand what you mean. Do you get the scroll in an itemrenderer using actionscript? If so, could you write an example in your answer to stick it as accepted? I will see Scroller.as as you recommend, but If you can help me a little more I will appreciate. I wish to find the solution.

Comment: I didn't go that far as to actually try and make it work.  My point is that the Scroller class uses VScrollBar/HScrollBar and does all of the heavy lifting for you. It's 1000+ lines of code, so I'm guessing that in all that code there are some additional steps that you need to do in your solution.  Point in fact, you need to set the `clipAndEnableScrolling` property on your viewport to true. Without that you'll never see scroll bars. Possibly there are other things you need to do.  Try setting that property to true in your solution. If that doesn't help, I'd try to use the Scroller again.

Comment: I tried that and the result is the same, I don't see any difference. I tried after read you answer yesterday, because of that I asked If you had the result. I'm going to read Scroller.as.   I don't understand why it doesn't work. I use a similar code (in actionscript too) but with datagroup instead of group, and the scroller works. Maybe the clue is the layout, I tried to add a verticallayout to the group, and nothing, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, scrolls need an actual width and height. It seems that the groups you're passing are actually empty, although they do have a set `percentWidth`. Add content into them.

If you're scrolling text, it might be more viable to use the built in scroll of the `TextArea`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not the case. As I said in the question, the group has content and if I remove super.addElement(scroller); the group content is shown. The content is not only text. It has bitmapimages, a shape, several stylabletext.. So the group is not empty, I can see it with no scroll.

Comment: try assigning the viewport after your group is populated and put a breakpoint on the line - ensure the group actually has correct `contentHeight` and `contentWidth`; i'd also suggest using `addElement()` instead of `super.addElement()` (it's a bit mystical)

Comment: Hahaha yesterday I dropped it, is there because I wanted to override that method for the classes that will inherit this one, itemrenderers  with scroll.

Comment: With populated you mean assigning viewport after addElement(scrollGroup); ?
Ok , I did, I have debugged and I know why the group is not showing. The group is not empty, is invisible. The public variable visible is assigned to true, but the private variable _visible is assigned to false. But I don't know why the group is internally invisible. The contentHeight/Width are equal to 0. Why? ><

Comment: I finally get the content! It's so simple as overriding method updateDisplayList, inside it I wrote scroller.width = unscaledWidth;    scroller.height = unscaledHeight; And now the group content is shown. The problem was in the scroller size. But unfortunable, it is not done. The scroller has horizontal scroll, then the horizontal scroll from the list doesn't work. I want a vertical scroll inside the itemrenderer, If the horizontal scroll of the list doesn't work this solution is not enough.

Comment: Solution: at the beginning add: scroller.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
Thank you for your guidance